# vuetify v-select with multiple options - getting selected/deselected option

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-select

I'm using `Vuetify` and its `v-select` component with `multiple` option enabled to allow selecting multiple options.

These options represent talent(candidate) pools for my CRM software.

What it needs to do is that when some option in v-select is checked, candidates from checked talent pool are fetched from API and saved to some array (let's call it `markedCandidates`), and when option is deselected, candidates from that pool need to be removed from `markedCandidates` array.

The problem is that `@change` or `@input` events return complete list of selected options. I need it to return just selected/deselected pool and information if it's selected or deselected, to be able to update the `markedCandidates` array.

My existing code:

```
<v-select return-object multiple @change="loadCandidatesFromTalentPool" v-model="markedCandidates" :item-text="'name'" :item-value="'name'" :items="talentPoolsSortedByName" dense placeholder="No pool selected" label="Talent Pools" color='#009FFF'>
  <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ item, index }">
    <span v-if="index === 0">{{ item.name }}</span>
    <span v-if="index === 1" class="grey--text caption othersSpan">(+{{ talentPools.length - 1 }} others)</span>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

Any idea how to solve this?

As I said, `loadCandidatesFromTalentPool(change)` returns complete array of `v-model` (`markedCandidates`)..

EDIT:
I found this solution, it's more of a workaround actually, would be nice if there was dedicated event for this situation:

https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/OByoOq?editors=1011

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is only one event related to changing values of `v-autocomplete` : `@change` (See https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#events). The `watch` approach is useful if you want to monitor only individual changes. However, if you plan to do this with more selectors, it could be better if you **create a custom reusable component** with a new attached event (in this example, for the *last change*).

```
Vue.component('customselector',{
  props:[
    "value",
    "items"
  ],
  data: function() {
    return {
      content: this.value,
      oldVal : this.value
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput (e) {
      this.$emit('input', this.content)
    },
    changed (val) {
      oldVal=this.oldVal
      //detect differences
      const diff = [
        ...val.filter(x => !oldVal.includes(x)),
        ...oldVal.filter(x => !val.includes(x))
      ]
      this.oldVal = val
      var deleted=[]
      var inserted=[]
      // detect inserted/deleted
      for(var i=0;i<diff.length;i++){
        if (val.indexOf(diff[i])){
          deleted.push(diff[i])
        }else{
          inserted.push(diff[i])
        }
      }
      this.$emit("change",val)
      this.$emit("lastchange",diff,inserted,deleted);
    }
  },
  extends: 'v-autocomplete',
  template: '<v-autocomplete @input="handleInput" @change="changed" :items="items" box chips color="blue lighten-2" label="Select" item-text="name" item-value="name" multiple return-object><slot></slot></v-autocomplete>',

})
```

Then you can use your component as simple as:

`<customselector @lastchange="lastChange" >...</customselector>`

```
methods:{
    lastChange: function(changed, inserted, deleted){
      this.lastChanged = changed
    }
}
```

The `changed` only shows items which are actually changed. I've added the `inserted` and `deleted` arrays to return new items added or removed from the selection.

Source example: https://codepen.io/fraigo/pen/qQRvve/?editors=1011

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
:item-text="'name'" :item-value="'name'"
```

by

`item-text="name" item-value="name"`